# Mouse takes a while to start working after boot

Tags: usb

I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) and a number of my USB devices have stopped working.  At least, they don't work for the first 3-5 minutes.  I have two mice (one wireless, one wired) and a camera, which seem to take Ubuntu 3-5 minutes to recognize after booting up.  Eventually, they do start to work, but it takes *ages*!

lsusb results: (when the mice are working...)

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c512 Logitech, Inc. LX-700 Cordless Desktop Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:3f11 Hewlett-Packard PSC-1315/PSC-1317
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

syslog entries for what seems (to my very untrained eye) to be the problem:

```
Oct 12 20:12:51 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   17.420117] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:12:57 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H goa[1879]: goa-daemon version 3.4.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
Oct 12 20:13:06 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   32.636107] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:13:06 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   32.852122] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Oct 12 20:13:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   47.964131] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:13:37 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   63.180115] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:13:37 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   63.396126] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Oct 12 20:13:47 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   73.804158] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 4, error -110
Oct 12 20:13:47 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   73.916190] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   84.324160] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 5, error -110
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   84.324197] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H udev-configure-printer: failed to claim interface
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H udev-configure-printer: Failed to get parent
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H udev-configure-printer: MFG:hp MDL:psc 1310 series  SERN:CN47CB60BJO2 serial:CN47CB60BJO2
Oct 12 20:13:58 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   84.768132] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:14:01 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H udev-configure-printer: no corresponding CUPS device found
Oct 12 20:14:13 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [   99.904185] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:14:29 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  115.144188] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:14:29 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  115.384178] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:14:44 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  130.520196] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:14:59 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  145.760179] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Oct 12 20:14:59 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  146.000173] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:15:10 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  156.408168] usb 5-3: device not accepting address 4, error -110
Oct 12 20:15:10 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  156.544188] usb 5-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:15:20 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  166.952181] usb 5-3: device not accepting address 5, error -110
Oct 12 20:15:20 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  166.952215] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.216164] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H mtp-probe: checking bus 6, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2"
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H mtp-probe: bus: 6, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.396138] input: Logitech USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/input/input16
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.396442] generic-usb 0003:046D:C00C.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input0
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.660187] usb 6-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H mtp-probe: checking bus 6, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-3"
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H mtp-probe: bus: 6, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.859045] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0006: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:13.1-3/input2
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.865086] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-3/6-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/input/input17
Oct 12 20:15:21 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H kernel: [  167.865291] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0007: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a] on usb-0000:00:13.1-3:1
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 139: unable get_string_descriptor -1: Operation not permitted
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 2040: invalid product id string ret=-1
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 139: unable get_string_descriptor -1: Operation not permitted
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 2045: invalid serial id string ret=-1
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 139: unable get_string_descriptor -1: Operation not permitted
Oct 12 20:15:24 REMOVED-GA-MA785GM-US2H colord: io/hpmud/musb.c 2050: invalid manufacturer string ret=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be for everyone, here's what i did to solve this problem for my mouse and keyboard. I put a PS2 keyboard and mouse into my computer. It works just fine.

Additionally, i installed a Synergy client on my Ubuntu machine, so that after i log in, i use the shared mouse and keyboard.

I hope this helps.

Love and peace,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue can appear due to another USB peripheral malfunction.
I had a very similar issue some days ago, with the same syslog errors:

```
Mar 19 07:56:27 XX kernel: [16.524042] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

I figured out the issue was not related to the OS, since I also had the same under Windows.

- Unplugging all USB connections (including internal motherboard connections, such as case's hub facade) did fix my problem. And by chance I could plug it again and everything worked fine. In my case an USB hub was guilty.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, this seems tough. I'm not 100% sure whether this will help or not, but you might want to consider trying out the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)' PPA. It's *highly* experimental, BUT they might have just the driver you need. (They had the driver for my graphics card, a Radeon HD 4350, which was previously getting ZERO hardware acceleration.) The one downside is that the packages build on each other, so you need the whole PPA just to get one little driver. :/

ANYWAY, this is not for everyone, but if you either love beta/experimental builds, or are very desperate, then this might be worth a shot.

To use this PPA, then press CTRL+ALT+T and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

**OR**, if the Terminal makes you queasy, go to your Update Manager (or Software Center,) choose `Edit`>`Software Sources`.
Then, choose the `Other Sources` tab and choose `Add...`.
Type `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu precise main` and click `Add Source`. Now, click `Close` and go back to the Update Manager.
Click `Check`, let it finish, and then click `Install`.

Comment: Thanks.  I may have to try that.  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 so I'm going to see if that improved anything first.

Comment: LMK if that works. Good luck!

Comment: Didn't seem to help much.  Still having issues.  I'm suspicious of the USB controller, and yet it seems to work ok in Windows.

Comment: Well, Windows is the king of drivers... Are you having any luck with the Xorg-edgers' drivers on 12.10? (12.10, Quantal Quetzal, is most definitely supported; they're already working on making drivers for the Raring Ringtail release.)